# ¿Cómo mejorar velocidad en programa que calcula el valor medio dentro de una lista con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estoy trabajando en un programa que calcula el valor medio de cada n datos, incluyendo el dato n hasta n - periodos. Tengo dos versiones que escribí, mejoré un poco la primer versión pero necesito procesar millones de datos en poco tiempo y la reducción de tiempo que conseguí no me es suficiente, los programas son estos: (la variable cierre solo es para simular los datos que tengo)

> primero.py

```
from random import uniform
from time import time

cierre = []
for i in range(100000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))

tiempo_inicial = time()

sma = []
periodos = 20
lista_temporal = []

for i in range(len(cierre)):
    if i < periodos:
        sma.append(0)
    else:
        for j in range(i, i - periodos, -1):
            lista_temporal.append(cierre[j])
        media = sum(lista_temporal) / periodos
        sma.append(media)
        media = 0
        lista_temporal = []

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial

print(tiempo_total)
```

> segundo.py

```
from random import uniform
from time import time


cierre = []
for i in range(100000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))

tiempo_inicial = time()

sma = []
periodos = 20
lista_inicial = []

for i in range(len(cierre)):
    if i > periodos:
        del lista_inicial[0]
        lista_inicial.append(cierre[i])
        media = sum(lista_inicial) / periodos
        sma.append(media)
    elif i < periodos:
        sma.append(0)
    else:
        for j in range(i, i - periodos, -1):
            lista_inicial.append(cierre[j])
        lista_inicial.reverse()
        media = sum(lista_inicial) / len(lista_inicial)
        sma.append(media)

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)
```

**Tiempos:**
primero: 0.833 s
segundo: 0.162 s

¿Cómo podría reducir el tiempo de segundo.py?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De primeras se me ocurre que puedes simplificar mucho tu código usando list comprehensions:

> Opción 1:

```
from random import uniform
from time import time


cierre = []
for i in range(10000000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))
periodos = 20

tiempo_inicial = time()

sma = [0]*periodos + [sum(cierre[i:i + periodos]) / periodos for i in range(1, len(cierre) - periodos + 1)]

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)
```

Simplemente usamos un ciclo `for` para crear sublistas `[i:i+periodos]` y sobre esas sublistas calculamos la media. La única diferencia es que voy creandolas hacia delante.

Podemos hacer que sea más eficiente aún si tenemos en cuenta que estamos haciendo. En cada iteración estamos añadiendo un elemento nuevo a la sublista y eleminamos el último. Podemos no usar `sum()` en cada iteración y simplemente añadir el nuvo valor y eleminar el anterior:

> Opcion 2:

```
from random import uniform
from time import time


cierre = []
for i in range(10000000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))
periodos = 20

tiempo_inicial=time()

suma = sum(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
sma = [0]*periodos + [suma/periodos]
for i in range (periodos+1, len(cierre)):
    suma = suma - cierre[i - periodos] + cierre[i]
    sma.append(suma/periodos)

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)
```

Este código aumenta su eficiencia con respecto al anterior cuanto mayor sea el periodo que uses.

Para una lista de 10 millones de elemntos y un periodo de 20 yo obtengo estos tiempos:

> segundo.py:...10.693564891815186 segundos
>   Opción 1:.........7.134753942489624 segundos
>   Opción 2:.........5.604719638824463 segundos

El resultado es el mismo que se produce usando tu segundo código en ambos casos, por ejemplo para:

```
cierre = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,2,1,4,5]
periodo = 3
```

Obtenemos el mismo resultado con los tres códigos si imprimimos `sma`:

```
[0, 0, 0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.333333333333333, 5.0, 3.3333333333333335, 2.6666666666666665, 2.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me gusto mucho tu segunda opción.

Comment: Se me paso algo, en tu segundo programa, si quisiera insertar un valor proveniente de una variable en vez de los ceros ¿como lo haría? no me viene idea a la cabeza.

Comment: @SamaelOlascoaga ¿Te refieres a los ceros iniciales? Simplemete cambia el 0 por el nombre de tu variable: `sma = [variable]*periodos + [suma/periodos]`.

Comment: Perdón, estaba haciendo burradas, ya vi como, gracias de nuevo.